# Acquiring IP from which Google Form submission was sent

Tags: jquery, forms, google-sheets

This is rather long wall of text but you do not need to read through it all, the main part of the post is below the second horizontal line - you do not have to read how did I analyze the issue :). Thanks in advance for any help!

---

I have a webpage with a custom form that sends submissions to a Google Spreadsheet (but original Google Form is also used by some of the users). I need to acquire IPs of users who use the custom form, although the input with IP should be hidden.

My first idea was to get the IP via jQuery and I have found a simple AJaX call here at Stackoverflow to do this. I wanted to create a form input that would be hidden using CSS and the IP acquired via AJaX would be put there (using jQuery) and then submitted together with the form. However, this way went out not to be acceptable for me, because if I wanted the Spreadsheet to receive the IP input, the additional form input field would have to remain in the original Google Form - which I do not want to happen.

Then I thought that my custom form should send the submission to two places (the Spreadsheet and some custom PHP script located on my server) at the same time (when the user submits) but I found out that a single form can only have a single 'action'. I didn not know if this can be done in any other way.

---

Finally, such an idea came to my mind: in the custom page, I will create a second form - that would be hidden and would contain two inputs, one with the IP and the second one which would be a copy of some of the first form's inputs (to let me identify who is owner of which IP). The submission would be sent to my server and processed with PHP; I could then compare the submissions stored in Spreadsheet and on my server.

When user would happily submit the main custom form, jQuery would copy one of the inputs to the hidden copy, get user's IP and submit the second form without knowledge of the user.

- Here is the question: is this the right way to do what I want to? Or there is some much simplier solution which I did not manage to find? I am not an 'IT pro' and thus I am afraid I am missing something.

Answer (score 0):

> ..if I wanted the Spreadsheet to receive the IP input, the additional form input field would have to remain in the original Google Form...

This statement isn't true. If your custom form is writing responses to the same spreadsheet that the Google Form is using, you can simply add another column to the spreadsheet, beside the table area used by Google Forms. This "field" would not be part of the Google Form, and would also be left out of any form summaries done by the Forms service.

Comment: Thanks for the answer :) I have achieved my aim in a bit other way already. But well, I am pretty sure that I had tried out what you have written about above and - maybe it was because of some mistake made by me - it did not work; spreadsheet accepted only those fields which were present in the Google Form. As soon as I had removed a field from the Google Form, Speradsheet stopped accepting the field value incoming from the custom form. I will try it out soon then, and return to you with a response.